# Best solution to label nodes in SVG dynamic tree (using D3.js)

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, tree, d3.js

I am trying to modify this D3.js example ([Dynamic Node-Link Tree](https://gist.github.com/999346)) by adding a specific label (SVG text) to each node, but unsucessfully.

If I understand correctly, after a brief look at SVG specs and D3 documentation, the best way would be to create SVG groups and move them around.

Unfortunately, this is not working, as the transitions have no effect on the groups.
Is there a simple(r) way I am not aware of?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for an effect where you switch the circles for text labels, you can do the following:

```
// Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
node.enter().append("svg:text")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.parent.data.x0; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.parent.data.y0; })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return "Node "+(nodeCount++); })
  .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("x", x)
    .attr("y", y);
```

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/pcwMa/4/

**Edit**

However, if you're looking to add labels alongside the circles, I would not recommend using `svg:g` in this case, because then you would have to use `transform`s to move the groups around. Instead, just double up on the circle nodes and text nodes like so in the update function:

```
  // Update the nodes…
  var cnode = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
        .data(nodes, nodeId);

  cnode.enter().append("svg:circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.parent.data.x0; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.parent.data.y0; })
      .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("cx", x)
        .attr("cy", y);

  var tnode = vis.selectAll("text.node")
        .data(nodes, nodeId);

  tnode.enter().append("svg:text")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .text(function(d) { return "Node "+(nodeCount++); })
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.parent.data.x0; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.parent.data.y0; })
      .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("x", x)
        .attr("y", y);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  cnode.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("cx", x)
      .attr("cy", y);

  tnode.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("x", x)
      .attr("y", y)
      .attr("dx", 4) 
      .attr("dy", 4); //padding-left and padding-top
```

A fiddle that demonstrates this can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/8ny7w/19/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was actually wondering how to have *both* circles and text. Is an SVG group the only option, to move both simultaneously?

Comment: Edited with the scenario you requested.